# Excel - reverse text to columns

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, formula

I am struggling to find a good way of doing this.
I have a file where some lines are hundreds of words long (comma separated) and some are only a few words long.
So performing a text to columns produces hundreds of columns, most of which are blank.
I have done my edits on the second column and now need to join everything back so that each line can be read in a text file and all words are comma separated once more.
Is there a formula that will know how many columns are in each line that are not blank and bring them all back into the first cell with comma separation?

I should add, I only have Excel 2010

I'd be happy to try a good powershell script solution if possible

Many thanks,

K

eg.

```
54325,354354,786756,6543,73644,23323,544,7233,64537,654,56,3456,754,876666,78,788
122,433
655,766
1233,7374,65436,65444,6577,85488,56767,8585876,6755,544445,67,67783,2233,466636
```

I use text to columns so I can work on contents of column 2, but then need it back in this format once done.
If I simply save as csv and open as text file, there are commas for every blank cell in each column

Comment: SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: It's unclear _what you are trying to do_ - could you perhaps post a (simplified) sample of the file contents, along with the intended end state?

Comment: I have added an example above

Answer (score 0):

Given a text file like the one you describe, you could simply split the lines manually:

```bsh
Get-Content .\input.txt |ForEach-Object {
  # split line into individual values
  $values = $_ -split ','

  # modify as needed
  if($values.Length -gt 2){
    $values[1] = "Make changes to column 2 here"
  }

  # stitch line back together
  $values -join ','
} |Set-Content .\output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to strip off the trailing commas from the short rows, as they don't produce blank columns, only empty cells. The columns have content from another row.  But here is VBA code to do what you request, in case that is a possibility for your usage:

- Assumption:  Starting point is your worksheet with each element of the CSV data you show above, in a separate cell.

[image]

- None of your `words` includes a comma, linefeed, or other character that requires enclosing the `word` in quotes.

This VBA code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub createCSV()
    Dim v, x, S As String, I As Long, RE As Object
        
v = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = ",*$"
    .MultiLine = True
    .Global = True
End With

ReDim x(1 To UBound(v, 1), 1 To 1)
With WorksheetFunction
For I = 1 To UBound(v, 1)

    'Replace trailing commas with nothing
    x(I, 1) = RE.Replace(Join(.Index(v, I, 0), ","), "")
Next I
End With

Open "D:\Users\Ron\Desktop\NewFile.csv" For Output As #1
For I = 1 To UBound(x)
    Print #1, x(I, 1)
Next I

Close #1
    
End Sub
```

I used a Regular Expression to remove the trailing commas.

results (in Notepad++):

```
54325,354354,786756,6543,73644,23323,544,7233,64537,654,56,3456,754,876666,78,788
122,433
655,766
1233,7374,65436,65444,6577,85488,56767,8585876,6755,544445,67,67783,2233,466636
```